# How to create a specific DOM structure with Elm.Html?

Tags: html, elm

people, 
I am trying to learn some Elm, and have the classical app-pattern taken from a tutorial (below). I would like to create a view that has a head(er), body and a footer. I see that elm.Html contains a header (and footer) function, so I tried to add it in the view function (below). I believe I need to create my own node ("t") which has DOM elements (header and div).

```
module App exposing (..)

import Html exposing (Html, node, header, div, text, program)

type Msg = NoOp

init =
    ("Hello", Cmd.none)


view model =
    node "t" [][header[][], div [][text "test"]]

update msg model =
    case msg of
        NoOp -> (model, Cmd.none)

subscriptions model = Sub.none

main =
    program
    { init = init
    , view = view
    , update = update
    , subscriptions = subscriptions
    }
```

When I look at the DOM on the client side it has this structure;

`<html><head></head><body><t><header></header><div>test</div></t></body></html>`

so it seems that my view function returns content within body-tags. So how would I be able to create a view that would have this structure?
`<html><header></header><body><div>test</div></body><footer></footer></html>`

Comment: you won't be able to do this as putting your header and footer outside of the `<body>` tag is not valid html.

Comment: @simon.Yes, thats true. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elm.Html doesn't provide access to the root of the DOM (the HTML node). Instead you give it a node to act as it's root (commonly a DIV). So considering your example, you'd have to create the HTML, HEADER, BODY, and the top-level DIV nodes in your HTML file. Elm can then take it from there.

```
view model =
    text "test"
```

But it's common to do something like this:

```
view model =
    div [] [ text "test" ]
```

Which would yield: `<html><header></header><body><div><div>test</div></div></body><footer></footer></html>`